Cálculo de costos con Inputs dinámicos
Por favor quisiera pedirles ayuda con un problema que tengo:
Tengo que elaborar una planilla, de asignación de recursos, para un conjunto de personas. Bajo los siguientes requerimientos:
•   El número de personas puede variar por actividad entonces el número de filas por planilla variará.
•   Para una actividad la persona puede pedir recursos según el área donde asista, estas pueden ser centro, periurbana y rural, siendo que puede ir a una, dos o tres áreas por actividad.
•   Cada área tiene un monto determinado por asignar, y según el número de días que se quede se multiplicará el numero de días de permanencia.
Ej. TotalCentro = MontoCentro * DiasPermaneciaCentro
Donde el TotalGeneral = TotalCentro + Total Periurbana + TotalRural
•   Además, el TotalSinImpuestos = TotalGeneral – (TotalGeneral* 0.21)
•   Se hace está asignación de recursos en un paso previo, cuando se planea la actividad, pero después de realizar la actividad los días pueden varias entonces la planilla inicialmente recupera los anteriores datos con la opción de modificación y los días pueden variar, es ahí donde tengo problemas pues cuando los días varían en los inputs con datos previos la suma total aumenta al dato inicial.
•   Se que las funciones están repetidas, pero la verdad es a única forma en la que pude solucionar el problema :(.
El detalle es que al recuperar información, cuando hay un dato en alguna de las casillas de días (en cualquier área) si la modifico , el total general se va aumentando lo que da un resultado erroneo.
Por favor podrían ayudarme
    $importeCentro =18444,83;
    $importePeriferia =13833,62;
    $importeRural = 9222,42;
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($personas as $row) {
   ?>
    <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $i;?></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['nombre'];?>" readonly></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['fecha'];?></td>
    <td>
    <input type="number" name="<?="diasCentro".$row[‘id’]?>" id="<?="diasCentro".$row[‘id’]?>" onKeyUp="multiplicaCentro(<?= $row[‘id’];?>, <?= $importeCentro;?>)" value="<?php echo $row['dias_centro'] ?>">
    </td>
    <td>
    <?php
    $costoCentro = $row['dias_centro'] * $ importeCentro;
    ?>
    <input type="number" name="<?= "montoCentro".$row[‘id’]?>" id="<?= "montoCentro ".$row[‘id’]?>" value="<?php echo $costoCentro?>">
     </td>
    <td>
    <input type="number" name="<?= 'diasPeriferia'.$row[‘id’]?>" id="<?= 'diasPeriferia'.$row[‘id’]?>" onKeyUp="multiplicaPeriferia(<?= $row[‘id’]; ?>, <?= $importePeriferia;?>)" value="<?php echo $row['dias_periferia'] ?>">
    </td>
    <td>
    <?php
 $costoPeriferia = $row['dias_periferia'] * $importePeriferia;
 ?>
    <input type="number" name="<?= 'montoIntermedia'.$row[‘id’]?>" id="<?= 'montoIntermedia'.$row[‘id’]?>" value="<?php echo $costoPeriferia?>">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="number" name="<?= 'dias_rural'.$row[‘id’]?>" id="<?= 'dias_rural'.    $row[‘id’]?>" onKeyUp="multiplicaRural(<?= $row[‘id’]; ?>, <?= $importeRural;?>)" value="<?php echo $row['dias_rural'] ?>"></td>
    <td >
    <?php
     $costoRural = $row['dias_rural'] * $importeRural;
    ?>
    <input type="number" name="<?= 'montoRural'.$row[‘id’]?>" id="<?= 'montoRural'.$row[‘id’]?>" value="<?php echo $costoRural ?>">
    </td>
    <td>
    <?php
     $totalGeneral = $costoCentro + $costoPeriferia + $costoRural;
    ?>
    <input type="number" name="<?= 'totalGeneral'.$row[‘id’]?>" id="<?= 'totalGeneral'.$row[‘id’]?>" value="<?php echo $ totalGeneral; ?>">
    </td>
    <td>
     <?php $descuento = $totalGeneral * 0.21;?>
    <input type="number" name="<?= 'impuesto'.$row[‘id’]?>" id="<?= 'impuesto'.$row[‘id’]?>"  value="<?php echo $descuento; ?>">
    </td>
    <td>
    <?php   $totalSinImpuestos = $ totalGeneral - $ descuento;?>
    <input type="number" name="<?= 'pagable'.$row[‘id’]?>" id="<?= 'pagable'.$row[‘id’]?>" value="<?php echo $ totalSinImpuestos; ?>">
    </td>


    </tr>
    <?php
    $i++;
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    <script>
    var total = 0;
    function multiplicaCentro(id, importe) {
        var dias_centro = $(`#diasCentro${id}`);
        var totalg = $(`#totalGeneral${id}`).val();
        var op = 0;
        var op = parseFloat(dias_centro.val()) * parseFloat(importe);
        $(`#montoCentro${id}`).val(op);
        
        sumaTotalSinImpuestos(id, op, totalg);
    }
    function multiplicaPeriferia(id, importe) {
        var dias_periferia = $(`#diasPeriferia ${id}`);
        var totalg = $(`#totalGeneral${id}`).val();
        var op = 0;
        var op = parseFloat(dias_periferia.val()) * parseFloat(importe);
        $(`#montoPeriferia${id}`).val(op);
        
        sumaTotalSinImpuestos(id, op, totalg);
    }
    function multiplicaRural(id, importe) {
        var dias_rural_p = $(`#dias_rural_p${id}`);
        var costo_p = $(`#totalGeneral${id}`).val();
        var op = 0;
        var op = parseFloat(dias_rural_p.val()) * parseFloat(importe);
        $(`#monto_rural_p${id}`).val(op);
        
        sumaTotalSinImpuestos(id, op, totalg);
    }

        function sumaTotalSinImpuestos(id, monto, costo) {
        total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(monto) + parseFloat(costo); 
        $(`#totalGeneral${id}`).val(total);
        }
    
     </script>```


Hola. Faltan detalles y precisiones en tu pregunta. Tal y como está planteada obligas a quien quiera ayudarte a entender por sí mismo todo un programa y una lógica y luego adivinar dónde está el problema exactamente. ¿Podrías indicar en qué parte del código ocurre el problema? ¿Podrías indicar además si hay persistencia de datos, por ejemplo, si guardas la información en una base de datos, explicando además si el problema es con esos datos ya guardados? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Muchas gracias por tus sugerencias, intenté editar el mensaje varias veces, pero tuve problemas para lograr cambiar la explicación

Tengo que elaborar una planilla, de asignación de recursos, para un conjunto de personas.

Primero se registra una actividad y una cantidad de participantes para esa actividad. Después se registran los viáticos que se asignan a cada participante esto varia según el área (centro, periurbana y rural) y los días de permanencia en cada área. Todo esto ya está registrado en una BD.
Entonces obtengo los datos de la BD y los reflejo en la planilla, hasta ahí todo bien.


El problema es cuando el usuario cambia los días de permanencia en cualquier área, el cálculo por área está bien, pero cuando se hace la suma de las tres áreas el calculo no es el correcto, pues como existe un valor previo los nuevos números se van sumando al anterior.
Para el cálculo por área se hace de la siguiente manera:    costoCentro =  ViaticoCentro * DiasPermaneciaCentro
costoPeriferia =  ViaticoPeriferia * DiasPermaneciaPeriferia
costoRural =  ViaticoRural * DiasPermaneciaRural
La suma total es:
Ej. totalGeneral= costoCentro + costoPeriferia  + costoRural

Por favor pulsa en [edit] y agrega las aclaraciones en la pregunta, indicando el trozo de código donde crees que está el problema.
